# Multibit Private Key Restore

Tags: multibit, backup, wallet-recovery

I backed up my private key and restored it into a new copy of Multibit (difference machine). The import was successful but the public key address has not been updated with my previous address.

I've done "Check Private Keys" which said it was successful as well as forced a resync with the blockchain. None of my old transactions are showing up.

Any thoughts? No doubt I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks!

#### Edit:

Thanks for the response! I verified through bitaddress.org that the private key I exported only matches the bitcoin address automatically generated when I created the new wallet.

But the old private key that I IMPORTED into this same wallet is nowhere to be found. Multibit says the import was a success. If this is true there should be TWO private keys in the export file; one for the auto-generated bitcoin address and one that matches the old imported private key.

I'd love to take the private key in my original export file and paste it into bitaddress.org to see if it matches my public address but my export file is encrypted. So I have to import into Multibit, enter the password and then export it unencrypted to obtain the private key.

Does anyone know of a way to decrypt an encrypted private key file without using Multibit?

Comment: You mean your bitcoin address is different? Than you must've backed up the wrong private key.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I verified through bitaddress.org that the private key I exported only matches the bitcoin address automatically generated when I created the new wallet. But the old private key that I IMPORTED into this same wallet is nowhere to be found. (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

For multibit classic, you can install openssl and use it in command lines to decrypt an encrypted private key file:

`openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -a -in multibit.key  -out key.txt  -pass 'pass:myPassword'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an offline copy of bit address.org to check private keys against addresses if you want. It's the wallet tab.

Answer (score 0):

effectively, with an offline copy, you can compare the private keys with the addresses if you want. It has served me in the past.